# weird warning in my disposeSplashScene

Tags: java, android, andengine

I am new Programmer ,

And I using andengine to develope a game, i juss keep on gettin this weird warning called 
The method disposeSplashScene() from the type SceneManager is never used locally
i wanted to initialize my splash scene and dispose is when its no longer required
here is the code

```
public void createSplashScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback)
    {
        ResourcesManager.getInstance().loadSplashScreen();
        splashScene = new SplashScene();
        currentScene = splashScene;
        pOnCreateSceneCallback.onCreateSceneFinished(splashScene);
    }

    private void disposeSplashScene()
    {
        ResourcesManager.getInstance().unloadSplashScreen();
        splashScene.disposeScene();
        splashScene = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That warning means you're never calling the disposeSplashScreen function anywhere.  Either you need to call it somewhere, or the function itself is unneeded and can be deleted.

If this function is meant to be called from an outside class, it should be public instead of private.